# Understanding Cloudkit record references

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I have a basic understanding of `CloudKit` containers and that public databases can't have zones but am having trouble understanding what rules apply to references to other records.

I have a record `AccountInfo` in a private zone which has a list of references to `Wine` records in the public database. When I create the a `UserObj` from the `AccountInfo` record like so:

```
public class UserObj: ObservableObject {
    var Fname: String
    var Lname: String
    var username: String
    var password: String
    var email: String
    var phoneNumber: String
    var pfp: UIImage
    var wines: [Wine]
    var recordID: String
    
    /**
     Creating UserObj from CK Record
     */
    init (ckrecord: CKRecord) async throws {
        self.Fname = ckrecord["FName"] as! String
        self.Lname = ckrecord["LName"] as! String
        self.username = ckrecord["Username"] as! String
        self.password = ckrecord["Password"] as! String
        self.email = ckrecord["Email"] as! String
        self.phoneNumber = ckrecord["PhoneNumber"] as! String
        
        //convert CKAsset to UIImage for pfp
        let imageAsset = ckrecord["PFP"] as! CKAsset
        var imageData = Data()
        do {
            imageData = try Data(contentsOf: imageAsset.fileURL!)
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
        self.pfp = UIImage(data: imageData)!
        //need to set this here to use self. in  async context
        self.recordID = ckrecord.recordID.recordName
        //convert list of references to array of wines
        //REFERENCE(List) in CloudDB stores a list of CKRecord.recordName's
        //Get the list of refrences as an array of strings
        //MARK: Figure out querying a reference
        let wineRefs = ckrecord["Wines"] as! [CKRecord.Reference]
        self.wines = []
        let cloudDB = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
        Task {
            do {
                //For each wine refrenced query them and create a 'Wine' object out of the refrence
                for wine in wineRefs {
                    let fetchedRecord = try await cloudDB.record(for: wine.recordID)
                    // Handle the fetched record
                    self.wines.append(try await Wine(fetchedRecord))
                }
                
            } catch {
                print("Error fetching record: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I receive this error:

> Error fetching record: Error fetching record <CKRecordID: 0xd84b835d0; recordName=E65602D5-8A9D-4DDE-A323-C2F6327A756E, zoneID=AccountInformation:**defaultOwner**> from server: Custom zones are not allowed in public DB

I am confused because only the `AccountInfo` record is private not the `Wine` record, so can someone provide insight to how to properly execute the query to create the wine objects?

For more context here is the `Wine` class:

```
class Wine: Identifiable{
    var type: String
    var vintage: String
    var vineyard: Vineyard
    let id: UUID //to make wine conform to identifiable
    
    init(_ ckrecord: CKRecord) async throws {
        self.type = ckrecord["Type"] as! String
        self.vintage = ckrecord["Vintage"] as! String
        //set as empty in order to use self in async
        self.vineyard = Vineyard()
        self.id = UUID()
        //create vineyard from record
        let vineyardRef = ckrecord["Vineyard"] as! CKRecord.Reference
        let cloudDB = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
        Task {
            do {
                let fetchedRecord = try await cloudDB.record(for: vineyardRef.recordID)
                // Handle the fetched record
                self.vineyard = Vineyard(fetchedRecord)
            } catch {
                print("Error fetching record: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
Here are the records in the database, I havent implemented created the record in actual code, this is a sample record I have created to implement an auto login feature.
[image: acount info record in database]

Comment: Please update your question showing how you create the wine references for an account info record. Right now you only show how you read those references but we need to see how they are created. In other words, show how you set the `"Wines"` property.

Comment: I don't know how you added the wine reference without any code but the reference has the wine record id in the account info zone. Since the wine records are in the public database, the record id needs to be in the default zone.

Comment: Okay that answers my question, it’s a database structure issue not a code issue.